# jQuery autocomplete validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the jQuery autocomplete to with a list of 800 values

```
    j$(function() {
    var availableTags = [item1,item2, item3,...];
    j$( "#stdcodes" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
    });
});
```

This works fine, what i want to do is limit or validate that the input in one the autocomplete values.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Do you want that the autocomplete list shows just one option each time ?

Comment: I want the autocomplete to filter as normal but to make sure that they can only select one of the autocomplete values and not add in their own. So the field value must be item1, item2 or item3 no other value can be entered.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$("#stdcodes").autocomplete({
    open: function(e) {
       valid = false;
     },
     select: function(e){
        valid = true;
     },
     close: function(e){
         if (!valid) $(this).val('');
     },
     source: availableTags
});

$("#stdcodes").change(function(){
    if (availableTags.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1){
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

Added extra validation, in case autocomplete doesn't execute

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ra96R/2/

Comment: Sorry not because i'm fast :) but only when i write something that doesn't appear in the list try xyz.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this way:

```
$("#stdcodes").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        /* apply validation on request.term: */
        var localResults = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(localArray, extractLast(request.term));

        response(localResults);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can it?

```
$("#my_input").autocomplete({

  source: function (request, response) {

    if ($.trim(request.term).length > 0) {
      // THIS MY REQUEST
    }
  }
})
```